# aiobotocore-aiohttp - Get S3 file content and stream it in the response

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aiohttp, botocore

I want to get the content of an uploaded file on S3 using botocore and aiohttp service. As the files may have a huge size:

- I don't want to store the whole file content in memory,
- I want to be able to handle other requests while downloading files from S3 (aiobotocore, aiohttp),
- I want to be able to apply modifications on the files I download, so I want to treat it line by line and stream the response to the client

For now, I have the following code in my aiohttp handler:

```
import asyncio                                  
import aiobotocore                              

from aiohttp import web                         

@asyncio.coroutine                              
def handle_get_file(loop):                      

    session = aiobotocore.get_session(loop=loop)

    client = session.create_client(             
        service_name="s3",                      
        region_name="",                         
        aws_secret_access_key="",               
        aws_access_key_id="",                   
        endpoint_url="http://s3:5000"           
    )                                           

    response = yield from client.get_object(    
        Bucket="mybucket",                      
        Key="key",                              
    )
```

Each time I read one line from the given file, I want to send the response. Actually, get_object() returns a dict with a Body (ClientResponseContentProxy object) inside. Using the method read(), how can I get a chunk of the expected response and stream it to the client ?

When I do :

```
for content in response['Body'].read(10):
    print("----")                        
    print(content)
```

The code inside the loop is never executed.

But when I do :

```
result = yield from response['Body'].read(10)
```

I get the content of the file in result. I am a little bit confused about how to use read() here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because the `aiobotocore` api is different than the one of `botocore` , here `read()` returns a `FlowControlStreamReader.read` generator for which you need to yield from

it looks something like that (taken from https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore/pull/19)

```
resp = yield from s3.get_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key='k')
stream = resp['Body']
try:
    chunk = yield from stream.read(10)
    while len(chunk) > 0:
      ...
      chunk = yield from stream.read(10)
finally:
  stream.close()
```

and actually in your case you can even use `readline()`

https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/c39355bef6c08ded5c80e4b1887e9b922bdda6ef/aiohttp/streams.py#L587

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.